# How to create month year drop down parameter in SSRS 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

In SSRS 2005, I need to provide a drop down to the user with month year labels for the last two months. 
For e.g. Jan 2010, Feb 2010, ... , Jan 2011, .... Dec 2011

I need this dynamically for the last two years (say).

Additionally, as user select one of the label, I need to pass the last date of the selected month-year combination to the query parameter.

Please help!

Sijoy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reporting from a SQL datasource, create a new dataset with a query to return the last date of each month within the required range (ie. the last two months) and the month-year description of each month - the details of the query will vary depending on the SQL database (MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle, etc). Populate the parameter from this new dataset, and set the value to be the date field and the label to be the description field.